# $e-2\approx0.71828$, but I got $1$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, exponential-function, fake-proofs

We know that:

$$\frac 1{2!}+\frac 1{3!}+\frac 1{4!}+\frac 1{5!}+\frac 1{6!}+\cdots =e-2\approx0.71828$$

But I am getting the above sum as $1,$ as shown below:

\begin{align}
S & = \frac 1{2!}+\frac 1{3!}+\frac 1{4!}+\frac 1{5!}+\frac 1{6!}+\cdots \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1{2!} + \frac {3-2}{3!} +\frac {4\times2-7}{4!}+\frac {5\times7-34}{5!}+\frac {6\times34-203}{6!}+\cdots \\[10pt]
& = \frac 1{2!}+\frac 1{2!}-\frac 2{3!}+\frac 2{3!}-\frac 7{4!}+\frac 7{4!}-\frac {34}{5!}+\frac {34}{5!}-\frac {203}{6!}+\cdots \\[10pt]
& = 1
\end{align}

Please indicate my mistake

Comment: The first two terms of your rearranged series sum to $1$. After that the terms cancel in pairs. To say that correctly you should look at the sequence of partial sums.

Comment: Are you sure that your rearrangement results in a convergent series? What's the general formula for the numerators? They seem to grow rather quickly.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a way to silently challenge us while the OP knows the answer.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Please do not misunderstand me , I really didn't knew initially that the procedure I used can't be applied and I have learnt a lot from all the answers below. I don't know why you misunderstood me.

Comment: @MrigankShekharPathak: I removed my vote.

Comment: Similar questions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/911293/summing-various-rearrangements-of-1-frac12-frac13-frac14-cdots?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2576166/rearranging-the-alternating-harmonic-series-and-finding-differences-in-its-sum

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Consider the numerators of the negative terms. The first one, call it $a_3$ for ease of notation, is $2$. Then they follow the recursion $a_{n+1}=(n+1)a_n-1$. What's the behavior of the sequence $\frac{a_n}{n!}$? Cases:

- It doesn't go to zero. In this case, your series doesn't even converge.
- It goes to zero but isn't summable. In this case, Riemann's theorem on conditional vs. absolute convergence will warn you that such a rearrangement may (or may not) change the value of the sum, or even cause it to fail to converge at all.
- It is summable. In this case such a rearrangement cannot change the value of the sum.

Also note that you are only considering the sequence of partial sums at *even* indices (i.e. the sum of 2 terms, 4 terms, ...). This can cause a sum that doesn't converge to look like it does; consider for a simpler example $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n$.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with any series.

You have a sum $a_1+a_2+a_3+a_4+\cdots$.

You can rewrite it as $1+(a_1-1)-(a_1-1)+(a_2+a_1-1)-(a_2+a_1-1)+(a_3+a_2+a_1-1)-\cdots$

The partial sums are $1, a_1, 1, a_2+a_1, 1, a_3+a_2+a_1, \dots$

Clearly splitting the elements in this way does not help any to sum the original series.

---

In response to the comments what OP has done in the question is rather split as $$a_1+(1-a_1)-(1-a_1-a_2)+(1-a_1-a_2)-\dots$$ with partial sums $a_1, 1, a_1+a_2, 1 \dots$

Whichever is used the "adjustment" term is of the form $\pm \left(1-\sum_{r=1}^n a_r\right)$. Here it tends in absolute value to $1-(e-2)=3-e$.

Comment: The example in the OP is a little bit more interesting because the "adjustments" go to zero, but not "summably fast". Your "adjustments" don't go to zero.

Comment: @Ian I think that the adjustments go to $3-e$ not $0$.

Comment: Oh, you're right, what the OP did is actually somewhat more dramatic than I thought. +1 for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

You are only shifting the difference at the infinity!

**EG**

note that $$1-\frac {203}{6!}=1-\frac {203}{720}=0.71805\ldots$$

> More in general, it can be easily shown that  **the remainder** is solution of the following **recurrence equation**:
>
> $$a_k=a_{k-1}-\frac{1}{k!}$$
>
> $$a_3=\frac13$$
>
> which quickly converges to the value: **0.281718... = 1-e**

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a(k)%3Da(k-1)-1%2Fk!,+a(3)%3D1%2F3

Answer (score 0):

After cancelling some of the terms, you are finally left with
{1}/{2!} +{1}/{2!} - some fraction.
I think you should recheck if the series you have written is converging. 
Although the numerators don't increase as fast as the denominators, I am not sure if you can completely ignore the further terms.

Comment: You're misunderstanding the meaning of the ...; the next term in the sum is $+\frac{203}{6!}$. The point is that it is set up so that after the first two terms, the terms come in $\pm$ pairs.

Comment: Yeah, I m sorry. I thought the summation ends there. I didn't read it properly